# Why does meta encourage low quality posts?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, meta

I don't really understand why anything on meta doesn't affect the reputation on the main site. I think this encourages people to post bad posts. It doesn't matter when their posts get downvoted, right?

I know that meta is designed to be a place for discussion, but shouldn't people get penalties when their posts are low quality? I see a lot of posts with downvotes recently. If people don't get a penalty when they post these, they will just keep going, right?

I know that you can flag questions as low quality but OP doesn't get any punishment! And I don't think you can be banned from posting on meta. I posted a lot of questions with downvotes and it didn't warn me that I will get banned.

Comment: If anything, public humiliation is probably worse than losing fake internet points.

Comment: you can be banned, it's intentionally much harder though. Posts still do get deleted if they aren't useful.

Comment: There used to be a reputation system on the old meta site (now called [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)). I'm guessing one of the reasons for not having reputation on child metas is that downvotes are often a form of disagreement, so they don't want to "punish" someone just for having a minority opinion.

Comment: It's a balance, we want people to discuss new ideas, we don't want them to ask a question that's been asked lots and lots of times before. MSE goes one way MSO the other.

Comment: `I see a lot of posts with downvotes recently` "recently", lol. http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=145

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I don't really understand why anything on meta doesn't affect the reputation on the main site.

Well, [voting is different on Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).  It's not *entirely* based on facts all the time; it's more often used to express disagreement.

Even though voting as it currently stands is arbitrary enough, having one's reputation on the main site plummet because people disagreed with something they said on Meta would seem *even more arbitrary*.

> I know that meta is designed to be a place for discussion, but shouldn't people get penalties when their posts are low quality?

If you ask enough poorly received questions, or make poorly received answers, you can be question and/or answer banned like you would on the main site.  The thresholds are much higher though since, again, voting is different here.

> I posted a lot of questions with downvotes and it didn't warn me that I will get banned.

You should probably stop doing that, or at least take into account the possible reasons *why* your posts aren't being well received, because you *can* be question banned.

Comment: I don't disagree with your last sentence but it might give the impression that you shouldn't post stuff that is against the standing sentiment on meta. I believe that would be the wrong message. If you post stuff aimed at improving current rules there will be resistance to change, expressed with down votes. Silencing those voices is a bad signal, IMHO.

Comment: @rene: Just so people don't get the wrong impression, if the FR is well-made (concrete enough to evaluate (and probably implement without much additional specification), including motivation, sound reasoning, recognizing and defusing most disadvantages), that resistance is for the most part absent. Though if it's a repeat of a common meme, things get harder in proportion to the lack of useful new ideas for addressing it, and the lack of incorporating of older posts.

Comment: With my up vote of your comment I have expressed my impression @Deduplicator

Comment: I disagree to use voting to determine which account should be banned at this, if so that is just discouraging someone to express idea to contribute the community

Comment: banning on meta should be manual only and based on content, not downvotes. I asked this question a few days ago: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333906/automatic-downvoting-bad-questions, which recieved a lot of downvotes, but a few upvotes and a lot of feedback about how the question was funny. Someone even edited it (with all the downvotes) to fix some formatting. Sometimes you ask meta questions just to trigger a debate, knowing that you'll get downvotes a lot because your ideas are radical. If users get banned easily, SO users won't ever take the risk of asking questions on meta.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre:  To my knowledge, the threshold for bans on Meta are **significantly** higher than they would be on Stack Overflow, since the way votes work can be different here.  You wouldn't have anything to worry about unless you had a sizable history of posting *really* bad suggestions/questions/discussions on Meta.