# Automatic downvoting bad questions

Tags: feature-request, downvotes

I know there are already mechanisms to warn users about dumping their code, resulting in very lengthy and difficultly understandable questions, long subjects, and I read that people still ignore all those warnings.

I came across very bad questions (at least 3 or 4 a day, specially in C/C++) which blatantly ignore those auto-warnings so my question is:

Would it be a good idea to automatically downvote those questions?

- long title: 1 downvote
- 1200-line snippet: 1 downvote

(Of course, if the user fixes the problems himself, downvotes would be reversed.)

So when the question is posted, it has already one or more downvotes, which makes it easier to track them down and close them. And if they're good, maybe edit them out or upvote them.

In addition, and just for laughs, some funny heuristic could be applied:

- "I get error": 1 downvote
- "sorry for my bad English": 1 downvote
- "Please help exam tomorrow urgent": 1 downvote
- "Student" in the code as a variable or structure: 1 downvote

(Sorry for my bad English. Please be kind to answer; it's a matter of life and death.)

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be a good idea to "nail down" auto-downvoting on such simple conditions. Just because the title is long or someone includes "Thanks" or "Sorry for my bad english" inside the question doesn't necessarily mean that the entire question is bad or downvote worthy. I think it is a bit more complex and more stuff to consider before you can tell if something is downvote worthy or not.

Comment: At least you made me laugh ... and how much I hate the low quality stuff posted and battle to get rid of it ... No, let's not do this. Just organize  more people that use their votes effectively.

Comment: There is a *much* more appropriate way to do this.  The system could limit the exposure of a question that appears to have quality problems, putting it on less "Interesting" pages of users.  Well, we can dream about it.

Comment: hey it's been implemented already: look at the downvotes :)

Comment: The great thing about the system as it is now, is this: users who blatantly disregard the warnings and still post very bad questions will typically get  downvoted, which will pretty quickly lead to a question ban, at which point they *must* deal with the quality / content issues and either learn how to participate or choose to leave the site.  Question (and answer) banning is a really powerful mechanism for making users acutely aware of their actions, and we just need to help the system work by downvoting posts that need it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No.

If you can come up with a system that does not have false positives, then you might as well outright block the questions from being posted.

If you cannot come up with such a system, any case of a false positive would end up in needless arguing. A warning message would be better, which is what we have today.